# Determine whether a matrix is separable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I wonder whether there is a simple way(e.g. if asked in exam) to determine if a matrix is separable. If yes, how can we write the separated parts? For example, Gaussian Blur kernel is separable.

$$\frac1{256}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
1&4&6&4&1\\
4&16&24&16&4\\
6&24&36&24&6\\
4&16&24&16&4\\
1&4&6&4&1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac1{256}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
1\\4\\6\\4\\1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
1&4&6&4&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have two matrices asked in old-exams. How to do my wish on the following matrices?

$$A = \frac1{4}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-2&-1\\
-2&16&-2\\
-1&-2&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
-1&-3&-1\\
0&0&0\\
1&3&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: If it's separable, each row is a scalar multiple of the same row.  In particular, the rank is $1$

Comment: ... and if you are column-oriented, each column is a scalar multiple of a same column...